# Vagrant "No input file specified."

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I am a python developer and my company wanted to do a project in PHP -laravel. Also he wanted me to start with `Vagrant`. So I came across this [simple tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-started-with-laravel-homestead) and tried to start with it. But still I'm getting error **No input file specified.**

I have been searching since whole day today for this issue, I have came across many posts which includes same query. I tried almost all the solutions from laravel.io and some [stack overflow queries](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=no%20input%20file%20specified.%20vagrant) But did not got the exact solution.

Directory Structure:

Git Cloned Homestead - `/home/laxmikant/Work/PHPWORK/Homestead`

Mapped location - `/home/laxmikant/Work/PHPWORK/codebase`  (totally empty directory)

Folders mapped `to` : `/home/vagrant/codebase` (Contains `Laravel` project)

Here is my `Homestead.yaml`

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/Work/PHPWORK/codebase #-- The path on my local machine 
      to: /home/vagrant/codebase  #-- The path from the vagrant box 

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/codebase/Laravel/public #-- The path from the vagrant box which is mapped with folders 

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

Also I am assuming that,By `Vagrant ssh` when the project is created using :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel --prefer-dist
```

It should also get synced with `codebase` directory of vagrant box
So the queries are:

- Is this assumption correct? if so why `map` and `to` are not getting synced? and
- What is the reason that I am getting the error `"No input file specified.`?

Comment: Can you login to your box `vagrant ssh` and check the contents of your /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory?

Comment: @LancePioch - There is nothing in that directory.

Comment: Use this tutorial, I always use it: http://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-get-homestead-vagrant-vm-running/

Comment: @AliErfani - Okay, Thanks. Will go through it. Basically the links seems for windows but I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: @AliErfani - did not help it. Anyway Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

It worked well with the following solutions:

`nginx configured manually` for my `homestead.app`

and changed, `Sync` locations in `Vagrantfile`

Comment: How did you do that, can you describe the process in detail? What does it mean to `nginx configured manually`, and what did you change inside (and where is it located the `Vagrantfile`?

Comment: @Pathros - Hi Sorry, I dont remember now. that was the only project I had worked in the PHP. After that I'm not in touch with Vagrant and nginx. You would need little R and D :(

Answer (score 3):

The assumption is correct whatever is in /home/vagrant/codebase will also end up in your ~/Work/PHPWORK/codebase.
After installing laravel via composer if the "no input file" error persists you probably need to reload configuration via running

```
vagrant provision
```

You should probably also add a homestead.app entry on your hosts file.

Comment: -Thanks for solution. I had tried that also. But that didn't work too.

Comment: Well can you try starting with vagrant up --debug and post the result here?

Comment: -Thanks for your great help. Forgot to mention here that it has got resolved yesterday, I added two things manually `nginx configured for my site homestead.app` and changed "sync" locations in `Vagrantfile`. Its working now.